# Trouble changing default search engine in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, search, search-engine

I'm trying to change my default engine in Safari (running Yosemite) from Google to DuckDuckGo and I'm not successful. I changed the default engine in "Safari→Preferences→Search". When I type into the address bar I see "DuckDuckGo search" in the suggestions, but then the search goes straight to google.

I checked the output of "defaults" and didn't see anything system-wide either. Did anyone encounter this problem?

Answer (score 3):

PEBKAC, sorry.

My problem was caused by the SafariKeyboardSearch extension. Disabling it helped.

Comment: You know you can mark your own answer as correct, right?